# How to create scrollable grid view of images

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, scrollable

Guys i am trying to create a scrollable grid view with 3 columns filled with images that have text in them but i am not sure how to add text ontop of the images (inside the box)

Edit: i keep getting exception errors. I added the circular images and now im missing just the text infront of them but i keep getting a list of errors similar to this:

Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPositionedBox#ba5f5 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT

```
 SizedBox(
                          width: width,
                          height: height / 3,
                          child: GridView.count(
                            crossAxisCount: 3,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                            children: [
                              CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                      "lib/assets/images/music_types/decor.jpg"),
                                  radius: 50),
                              CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                      "lib/assets/images/music_types/decor2.jpg"),
                                  radius: 50),
                              CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                      "lib/assets/images/music_types/decor3.jpg"),
                                  radius: 50),
                              CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                      "lib/assets/images/music_types/decor4.jpg"),
                                  radius: 50)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: You have to use stack or container with boxDecoraion and imageDecoration

Comment: can you add an image, that you like to archive ?

Comment: I added some code to the question. Below the code i have posted there are 2 buttons and above it there is a row of images and a title text. Now whenever i run, the 2 buttons at the bottom are missing but the widgets at the top (title and row of images) are showing fine

Comment: Check out [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view), I used it for similar task and worked well.